# React action function with dispatch as parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, action

I have the following action:

```
export const remove = (id, index, event) => ({
  type: 'REMOVE',
  id: id,
  index: index
});
```

I use it with store.dispatch:

```
onClick={(e) => store.dispatch(remove('item', index))}
```

I need to change the way I call remove, instead of calling store.dispatch(remove) directelly I want to call a function showAlert which is calling a function received as parameter (remove in my case), but I can not figure out how to send store.dispatch(remove) as parameter.
I tried to change my remove function to:

```
export function removeInterview(id, index) {
    return (dispatch) => ({type: 'REMOVE',id: id, index: index}); 
};
```

And used it like this:
 onClick={(e) => showAlert(remove, [id, index])}

And showAlert is a action and in the reducer i set some states in a component and will call the function given as parameters, something like this:

```
onConfirm() {
        this.state.data.onConfirm.func.apply(null,this.state.data.onConfirm.params);
}
// this.state.data.onConfirm.func.apply - the function I want to send as params (store.dispatch(remove)
```

Comment: why do you want to send "store.dispatch(remove)" instead of just "remove", import store in your file where there is showAlert and just store.dispatch(paramFunction) ?

Comment: Because in my file containing show alert I use also other functions which are not from the store so I don't want to use dispatch on all (some of the functions are mapped to the container), and where I use remove, the component is not a container.